# Hibernate-validator Groups with Spring MVC

Tags: java, hibernate-validator

I'm using hibernate-validator 4.3.1 and Spring MVC 3.2.3.

My application has a bean with the following properties and annotations (I've removed most of them to make it simple):

```
public class Account {
  @NotEmpty(groups = GroupOne.class)
  private String name;

  @NotEmpty(groups = GroupOne.class)
  private Date creationDate;

  @NotEmpty(groups = GroupTwo.class)
  private String role;

  @NotEmpty(groups = GroupTwo.class)
  private String profile;

  //getters and setters
}
```

As it is showed, there are two groups of validations because the application has a wizard-form composed of two steps: in the first step the name and creationDate fields are filled by the user and in the second step the role and profile fields.

I add some Controller methods as example:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/account/stepOne", method = "POST")
public String stepOne(@ModelAttribute @Validated(GroupOne.class) Account account, BindingResult bindingResult) {
  //Implementation
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/account/stepTwo", method = "POST")
public String stepTwo(@ModelAttribute @Validated(GroupTwo.class) Account account, BindingResult bindingResult) {
  //Implementation
}
```

The above methods specify which validation has to be applied by @Validated annotation.

Until now everything works fine, but I have some problems when I want to reuse that bean in another form. This form displays all the fields of the bean and the controller's method which receives the submit is the following:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/account/stepOne", method = "POST")
public String stepOne(@ModelAttribute @Validated Account account, BindingResult bindingResult) {
  //Implementation
}
```

As you can see, the name of the group has been removed from the @Validated annotation because I want to apply all the validations defined in Account bean.

However, it didn't work and the only way to make it work has been to add the Default group to the bean's properties, as so:

```
public class Account {
  @NotEmpty(groups = {GroupOne.class, Default.class})
  private String name;

  @NotEmpty(groups = {GroupOne.class, Default.class})
  private Date creationDate;

  @NotEmpty(groups = {GroupTwo.class, Default.class})
  private String role;

  @NotEmpty(groups = {GroupTwo.class, Default.class})
  private String profile;

  //getters and setters
}
```

Is there a more elegant way to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no more elegant way. Validating without specifying a group will validate the default groups. Hence you have to add it as described. The only other alternative is to explicitly validate all groups you are interested in via `@Validated({GroupOne.class, GroupTwo.class})`. I guess it is a matter of taste what you prefer.

Comment: I realized I could define the validations groups inside @Validated, but I didn't like it either. Anyway, thanks for your answer.

Comment: Had to realize that no matter what group you name the defaults (meaning, properties without a group, don't confuse it with `Default.class` used in the questions code) are always validated as well. As this might not be what one expects when explicitly naming a group, I just wanted to point out.

Comment: Here is the documentation on grouping constraints for more info https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/5.4/reference/en-US/html_single/#chapter-groups

Comment: @Alex Biddle OK, let's put the examples in telle's question aside for a while. Assume we have three properties _a_, _b_ and _c_. Now, _a_ is assigned to 'GroupA.class' and _b_ to 'GroupB.class'. _c_ has no group at all. If you annotate '@Validated({GroupA.class})' then _a_ **and** _c_ will be validated, not just _a_ (at least it was in the version I use when I wrote that comment). It took me hours to realize that this is default behavior and not an error in my coding.

Comment: @MyBrainHurts I understand now, thanks for taking the time to reply

Answer (score 2):

if you extend your Group Interface with Default, it should take care of itself.

Like

```
public interface Group1 extends Default {}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **@Valid**:

```
public ModelAndView myMethod(@ModelAttribute @Valid MyDto myDto, BindingResult result){

  if(result.hasErrors()){
    ....
}
```