# Steps for creating Group Validation Using Hibernate Validation

Tags: hibernate, validation, jakarta-ee, bean-validation

I don't really understand the steps for creating Group Validation using Hibernate. Please can anyone help. I have two classes from databases where some fields from both classes should be grouped and validated, using official hibernate docs I take next steps:
Lets assume I have two classes with fields:

```
    public class Tickets implements Serializable {
    @NotNull(groups=GroupLotsAndTicketsValidation.class)
    @Size(groups = GroupLotsAndTicketsValidation.class)
    @NotBlank
    private string Amount;
    //and other fields..
    //getters and setters
    }
```

This was my first class. Here is the Second:

```
public class Lots implements Serializable {

@NotNull(groups = GroupLotsAndTicketsValidation.class)
@Size(groups = GroupLotsAndTicketsValidation.class)
@NotBlank(groups =GroupLotsAndTicketsValidation.class)
private String title;
@NotNull(groups = GroupLotsAndTicketsValidation.class)
@NotBlank(groups =GroupLotsAndTicketsValidation.class)
private String fullWeight;
//and other fields..
//getters and setters...
    }
```

This was My second class. 
Also I read that I should create one interface per class. However as I think It should be done if i want to create my own annotations. 
Should I create interfaces and what steps to take next. Thanks in advance

Comment: Your question seems duplicate. First one answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24712365/5728095)

Comment: @Sergii thanks for a link, however I need exact steps, what should I create what should I add to interface class if I will create it. Thanks for understanding.                                                                                                         P.S. in the link the guy didn't show where he got class  GroupOne.class and GroupTwo.Class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Group interface is not for implementation. It's a marker of validation. This marker you can use in tests. If you use powerful frameworks like spring, you can use marker on `@Controller` or any bean level.

For example. You have Entity `Profile`

In your rest API you need to have `POST` (create) and `PUT` (update) operations. So you'll have

```
@RestController
public class ProfileController {
  @PostMapping("/profile")
  public Calendar insert(@RequestBody @Valid Profile profile) {
    return null; // implement me
  }
  @PutMapping("/profile/{profileId}/")
  public void update(@PathVariable String profileId, @RequestBody @Valid Profile profile) {
    // todo implement me.
  }
}
```

In the entity you have to put `id` value before use any update operation (for example only, this case valid for create operation if id-key is managed on java side). So it should not be `null` in your validation logic.

```
public class Profile {
  @Id
  @NotNull
  private Long id;
  private String name;
  @NotNull
  private String email;
}
```

And if you'll try to use it you'll get ui nonNull constraint exception in create operation. You do not need `ID` notNull validation in your create operation, but you need one in your update operation! One of solutions is to create different dto objects with their own validation, other - remove validation from id field, and alternative solution is to use:

```
public class Profile {
  @Id
  @NotNull(groups = UpdateOperation.class)
  private Long id;
  private String name;
  @NotNull
  private String email;
}

public interface UpdateOperation {}
```

and add changes into controller (`@Valid` (JSR-303) should migrate to validator annotation that supports validation groups spring provides `@Validated`):

```
  @PostMapping("/profile")
  public Calendar insert(@RequestBody @Validated Profile profile) {
    return null; // implement me
  }
  @PutMapping("/profile/{profileId}/")
  public void update(@PathVariable String profileId, @RequestBody @Validated({UpdateOperation.class}) Profile profile) {
    // todo implement me.
  }
```

As result you do not need create dto per rest operation and you have flexible validation on your rest level.

Also I hope you already red:

- [Chapter 2. Validation step by step](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.2/reference/en-US/html/validator-usingvalidator.html#validator-usingvalidator-annotate);
- [Chapter 5. Grouping constraints](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/5.1/reference/en-US/html/chapter-groups.html#chapter-groups);
- [Validation in spring](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html).

Comment: I'm adding the `@Validated` annotation but is not working.

Comment: @LinuRadu if you want me help you, add here link on your question (I need all details). I can't help in so abstract case. You know: abstract question gets abstract answer.